# The error is in jaspersoft studio and they are no viable alternative at input 'month' , no viable alternative at input 'year' , missing EOF at '='

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have written SQL query in jaspersoft studio

```
Select Orderid , Orderdate , Shipcity,   
year(Orderdate) as year, month(Orderdate) as month 
from Orders 
where Orderid IN
(
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Orderdate) , 
          EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Orderdate) 
    from Orders 
    where (
        year(Orderdate) =  Startyear 
        AND
        month(Orderdate) = Startmonth 
    )
)
```

This is the query

Comment: What is the flavor of SQL which your Jasper Studio is using?  We need to know that in order to correct your query.

Comment: The flavor of sql is  postGreSQL ,and also I tried ths query in SSMS as MSSQL

Comment: Can you help me @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL, as written, doesn’t make a lot of sense. The subquery after

```
where Orderid IN
```

needs to return a single field containing order Ids but instead you’ve written something that returns 2 fields, neither of which appear to be an Order Id

Comment: So need to replace orderid with oderdate

Comment: what I did is I need to add filter of date as dropdown of year and month so created parameters for year and month ,for that I used extract for both year and month

Comment: So just use SELECT Orderid

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, still the same error is present at 2nd where

Comment: Do you know any other syntax of this query @NickW